# Buscar en un rango de ip's, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy realizando una consulta para obtener direcciones ip dado un rango, por ejemplo:

Obtener las ip's que esten entre 192.168.0.0 y 192.168.0.255

La consulta que estoy usando es:

```
SELECT dir_ip
FROM nic
WHERE dir_ip
BETWEEN '192.168.0.0' AND '192.168.0.255'
ORDER BY dir_ip
```

Las direcciones ip están almacenadas como texto en la base de datos, el problema de esa consulta es que no se por que no retorna todas las direcciones ip, que en total deberían ser 256 y solo me trae 177 en total.

**¿Que consulta podría realizar para lograr obtener todas las ip's dentro del rango dado?.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prueba con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT dir_ip
FROM nic
WHERE CAST(dir_ip AS INET)
BETWEEN CAST('192.168.0.0' AS INET) AND CAST('192.168.0.255' AS INET)
ORDER BY CAST(dir_ip AS INET);
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue util :)

Answer (score 1):

Solo voy a agregar un poco de información a la respuesta de Neyer:

El "problema" es que como campo de texto 192.168.0.3 es mayor a 192.168.0.255, de ahí que no te funcione la búsqueda.

Postgres tiene tipos de campos específicos para estos datos, se llaman [Network Address](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html), y entre esos tipos, está **inet** que forma parte de la respuesta en mención, este tipo de campo acepta direcciones IPv4 o IPv6 (y opcionalmente su subnet). Estos tipos de campo incluyen chequeo de errores de los datos (input) y algunas funciones y operadores especiales:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-net.html

Comment: Gracias por la informacion!!! ahora ya se cual era el error.